# Google FusionTable not returning correct result - hidden limit?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Beginning learning the FusionTable API.  I have a fairly small 'Hello World' example Google FusionTable with ~32,000 records.  But simple queries seems to return patently wrong results, and i wonder if I'm flat out missing something or there's a limit I'm unaware of?

Try this [Source table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1xxJtCuJ8V7D6nTEOdeNPGS7Q--VdugQqLtjjYgQ) using [Online FusionTable API SQL client](http://simplehomepage.appspot.com/google/google-fusion-table-query-javascript-sql-client.htm) using this table ID:

```
1xxJtCuJ8V7D6nTEOdeNPGS7Q--VdugQqLtjjYgQ
```

`SELECT COUNT(SEX) FROM 4546155` returns `32,778`

But `SELECT SEX, COUNT() FROM 4546155 GROUP BY SEX` returns:

```
[table] => object
  [cols] => object
     [0] => SEX
     [1] => count()
  [rows] => object
     [0] => object
         [0] => 1
         [1] => 5431
     [1] => object
         [0] => 2
         [1] => 4025
```

Note that 5431 + 4025 = 9456, not 32,778.  I would have expected 18,876 and 13,902, respectively, which do sum to 32,778:

Does the system silently stop aggregate queries at 10,000 records in the source table?  Any suggestions?

Comment: I wonder if FT is caching results.  I think I first ran this query after uploading the data, but while the import was about 40% complete.   Now those queries that I ran then all seem stuck with results based on partial data.  
-- I reloaded the same table into a new FT and get the correct results. 
-- I did a query on another field on this table that I had not been querying during import and that got correct results

Does FT cache query results for performance?  I can see why they'd want to.  Is there a way to clear the cache?

Answer (score 0):

I believe FT is caching results on queries, and these caches can be wrong if the queries are first run on incomplete data.

Queries on fields (e.g. SEX, ETHUN) that I ran for testing after uploading the data -- but before the counter said '100% complete' -- return instantaneously (< 0.1 sec) with results that look like they're based on half the data.  While similar queries on other fields (e.g. COPD, ASTHMA) return slowly (10-30 sec or more) with correct results (or a timeout with a 503 error) and then return correct results, and then return instantaneously after that.